# Is there a point in hyperparameter tuning for Random Forests?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, overfitting, hyperparameter-tuning

I have a binary classification task with substantial class imbalance (99% negative - 1% positive). I want to developed a Random Forest model to make prediction, and after establishing a baseline (with default parameters), I proceed to hyperparameter tuning with scikit-learn's GridSearchCV.

After setting some parameters (e.g. `max_depth`, `min_samples_split`, etc.), I noticed that the best parameters, once GridSearch was done, are highest **max** parameters (`max_depth`) and the smallest **min** parameters (`min_samples_split`, `min_samples_leaf`). In other words, GridSearchCV favored the combination of parameters that fits most closely to the training set, i.e. **overfitting it**. I always thought that cross-validation would protect from this scenario.

Therefore, my question is 'What is the point of GridSearch if the outcome is overfitting?' Have I misunderstood its purpose?

My code:

````
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=random_state)

param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [100, 200],
    'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini'],
    'max_depth': [5, 10, 20],
    'min_samples_split': [5, 10],
    'min_samples_leaf': [5, 10],
    'max_features': ['sqrt'],
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'class_weight': ['balanced']
}

rf_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf,
                       param_grid=param_grid,
                       scoring=scoring_metric,
                       cv=5,
                       verbose=False,
                       n_jobs=-1)

best_rf_grid = rf_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I would address the extreme imbalance first to get a more reliable score, try oversampling or under (I prefer over).

Then try with conservative parameters, like max_depth only until 10.

I prefer to use XGBoost over Random Forest though, it has an early stopping parameter to help prevent overfitting, although one still has to be conservative especially in the max_depth.

Then I use Optuna for hyperparameter tuning, it can also be used for Random Forest and is so much faster than  GridSearchCV (especially with a huge dataset).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have a case of extreme imbalanced dataset. So until and unless you address that problem, whatever you do will not be much effective.

Here are some things you can try to address data imbalance:

1.) **Oversampling** or **Undersampling**. `imblearn` can help you with that.

2.) **Ensemble learning models** : Using **bagging or boosting models** for imbalanced dataset. You are already using bagging model (random forest). You could also try the **balancedbaggingclassifier** present in `imblearn` library. [Here](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedBaggingClassifier.html) is the documentation for that. Also try some boosting models like **XgBoost, CatBoost** etc.

3.) **Choose the right metric for evaluation**: You have not mentioned which evaluation metric you are using. I would suggest `f1_score` but you can also use `precision_score` and `recall_score` depending on your problem statement.

4.) **Get more data**. This might be the most effective of all. Get more data specially for the minority class which will decrease the imbalance effect.